# Select fields from two tables with Speedment

Tags: java, sql, speedment

I want to select fields from two tables with Speedment ORM, and show registers by System.out.println.

This is my main query:

```
        return AMDB.INSTANCE.interface_Manager().stream().filter(Interface_.INTERFACEID.contains(s))
            .map(AMDB.INSTANCE.abstractcomponentManager().finderBy(Interface_.INTERFACE_COMPONENT_E_ID))
            .flatMap(AMDB.INSTANCE.concretecomponentManager().finderBackwardsBy(Concretecomponent.ABSTRACTCOMPONENT_E_ID))
            .map(cc -> cc.getConcretecomponentCamCamid())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And I want to get/select fields from diferent tables:

```
    StreamComposition.concatAndAutoClose(
            AMDB.INSTANCE.interface_Manager().stream().filter(Interface_.INTERFACEID.contains(s))
                    .map(i -> i.getInterfaceid()),

            AMDB.INSTANCE.interface_Manager().stream().filter(Interface_.INTERFACEID.contains(s))
                    .map(AMDB.INSTANCE.abstractcomponentManager().finderBy(Interface_.INTERFACE_COMPONENT_E_ID))
                    .map(ac -> ac.getComponentname()),

            AMDB.INSTANCE.interface_Manager().stream().filter(Interface_.INTERFACEID.contains(s))
                    .map(AMDB.INSTANCE.abstractcomponentManager().finderBy(Interface_.INTERFACE_COMPONENT_E_ID))
                    .flatMap(AMDB.INSTANCE.concretecomponentManager().finderBackwardsBy(Concretecomponent.ABSTRACTCOMPONENT_E_ID))
                    .map(cc -> cc.getConcretecomponentCamCamid())
    ).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Maybe as:

SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN tabl2 ON table1.id = table2.id

or

FROM table1, table2

I have found one way:

```
        Map<Abstractcomponent, List<Interface_>> map0 = AMDB.INSTANCE.interface_Manager().stream().filter(Interface_.INTERFACEID.contains(s))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AMDB.INSTANCE.abstractcomponentManager().finderBy(Interface_.INTERFACE_COMPONENT_E_ID)));
```

But I want to achieve the fields from last joining table with the values `Map<String, List<Interface_>>,` where the "String is a field from "concretecomponentManager" table

Comment: And what did you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Speedment (as of the latest release 3.0.13) does not support JOINs. However, you can create a VIEW in the database that JOINs the two tables together and then generate code from that using Speedment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the example from the question, but wanted to remark that
speedment actually does support joins:

```
Map<Actor, List<Film>> filmographies = filmActors.stream()
.collect(
    groupingBy(actors.finderBy(FilmActor.ACTOR_ID), // Applies the FilmActor to ACTOR classifier
        mapping(
            films.finderBy(FilmActor.FILM_ID), // Applies the FilmActor to Film finder
            toList()                           // Use a List collector for downstream aggregation.
        )
    )
);
```

See [joins](https://speedment.github.io/speedment-doc/speedment_examples.html#join), [many to many](https://speedment.github.io/speedment-doc/speedment_examples.html#many-to-many-relations) and [pivot data](https://speedment.github.io/speedment-doc/speedment_examples.html#pivot-data).